# "Cannot find symbol" error in open source software project

Tags: java, ant

I am looking to edit an open source software which I downloaded from SourceForge, but before editing anything I decided to run the "build" xml file through ANT, and create a jar executable to test everything initially.

As soon as I build the project, it displayed several errors in one of the class. All the errors are for "Cannot Find symbol..."

But when I opened the file in Eclipse, everything seems to be fine. So what should I do about this, from where should I proceed next?

If needed, I can also post the link of the software that I am talking about.

Comment: One word: CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Try using different version of ant. That will resolve your problem.